# How can I rename a network on my iMac?

Tags: networking, rename

I just bought several WiFi extenders,Repeaters,for my iMac using Mojave 10.14.6 (18G87)version  and they have wierd Network names. I would like to change the Names to something like Patio, Den, Bedroom etc. If one goes out, then it would be easy to check on the one not working.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your terminal on your mac while connected to one of the wifi extended you are connected to and now you need to get the default gateway IP address.
2. [Follow these steps](http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/15/find-default-gateway-ip-address-mac-os-x/)
3. Open your browser an enter the IP address into your browser
4. Log into your wifi repeater's admin home page and change the **Network SSID**